# OpenAPI spec - requirement of filename in multipart/form-data

Tags: api, reverse-engineering, openapi

I'm reverse-engineering an API with an endpoint `/submit`, that accepts the type `multipart/form-data` content. On the webpage of the service, there is a form to upload plaintext files, so the body of the request should look (and according to devtools it actually looks) like this:

```
-----------------------------16987925643278910326523687321
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="output"; filename="aaa.txt"
Content-Type: text/plain

some text

-----------------------------16987925643278910326523687321--
```

My OpenAPI specification of the request body is as follows:

```yaml
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data: 
      schema:           
        type: object
        properties:     
          output:            
            type: string
```

This works *almost* perfectly, but the code generated from the specification doesn't include the `filename="something.txt"` in its requests, which the API for some reason needs.

OK: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="output"; filename="aaa.txt"`
Error: `Content-Disposition: form-data; name="output"`

How can I specify in the OpenAPI specification, that the part must always be provided with the filename?

Comment: @Sidou Gmr thanks for your edit, I'm not a native English speaker :)

Comment: By the "code generated from the specification" do you mean try-it-out requests in Swagger UI? Or did you generate some client SDK from the OpenAPI definition and you mean the code in that SDK? Or something else?

Comment: If you add `format: binary` after `type: string`, does it resolve the issue?

Comment: I mean the client SDK, but I think Swagger UI would behave the same @Helen

Comment: And yes, `format: binary` worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As correctly pointed out by [@Helen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113116/helen), the solution is to add `format: binary` after `type: string` in the specification:

```yaml
requestBody:
  content:
    multipart/form-data: 
      schema:           
        type: object
        properties:     
          output:            
            type: string
            format: binary # <- THIS
```